# armadillo c++ typecast double matrix mat to float matrix fmat

Tags: c++, armadillo

How can I typecast a mat to fmat. One of my function is returning mat. However in the interest of memory, I want to convert it to fmat. How can I type cast it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert between matrix types using [conv_to](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#conv_to):

```
mat A = my_function();
fmat B = conv_to<fmat>::from(A);
fmat C = conv_to<fmat>::from(my_function());
```

Alternatively, you could change your function into a template; for example:

```
template <typename T>
Mat<T> other_function() {
  return Mat<T>(4,4);
}

...

fmat D = other_function<float>();
mat F = other_function<double>();
```

Comment: What about vector? For eg., double vector vec to float vector fvec? The above solution works for vector too. Thanks!!!!